# i'm unable to get the result from the controller method in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

i'm sending the ajax call to the controller method then the method checks if data is present then echo **true** if data is not found in database then echo **false**

the problem is that i'm unable to get the true and false of controller method in ajax success function

**Controller**

```
public function ajax_load()

    {

            $project_id =$this->input->post('account');

             $this->db->select('Project_id');

            $this->db->from('proposal');

            $this->db->where('Project_id',$project_id);

            $query = $this->db->get()->row();

            if($query){
                echo "true";
            }else{
                echo "false";
            }

        }
```

**Ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
                  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>proposal/ajax_load",
                  type: 'POST',
                  data : {"account" : project_id}, 
                  success: function(result){
                      if(result==="true"){
                        $("#err").show();
                        $("#err").html("Project_id already exist");
                        $(".btn").prop('disabled', true);
                       }else{
                        $("#err").hide();
                        $(".btn").prop('disabled', false);
                       }
                    }
        });
```

Comment: what do you get when console.log(result)?

Comment: What you get in  network tab in console ?

Comment: i get true and false but its not working in if else condition

Comment: Can you share screenshot?

Comment: when i get true first block run and when i get false then again first block code run else block did'nt run

Comment: @dani     after ajax success function you write var result = $.trim(result);   & let me know its working or not?

Comment: i solved my problem btw thanku for your valuable time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return true or false value from controller like

```
if($query){
            $arr=["true"];
            echo json_encode($arr);
        }else{
            $arr=["false"];
            echo json_encode($arr);
        }
```

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo base_url();?>proposal/ajax_load",
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              data : {"account" : project_id}, 
              success: function(result){
                  if(result[0]==="true"){
                    $("#err").show();
                    $("#err").html("Project id already exist");
                    $(".btn").prop('disabled', true);
                   }else if(result[0]==="false"){
                    $("#err").hide();
                    $(".btn").prop('disabled', false);
                   }
                }
    });
```

Comment: what result values you are getting in result of ajax success?

Comment: when i tried consol.log(result) i get true and false but in if condition it just not working

Comment: its not working my friend btw thanku for your feed back

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you and besides what kind of query is that that you are writing. Next time try to show your full codes for faster help. Stacoverflow are full of Engineers and no one is stealing your code so I wonder why sending it half way.

Okay Ensure that your backend is working fine

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

         $(document).ready(function(){


         //$('#result').click(function(){

         var project_id = '1';





        $('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('Please Wait. Data is being Loaded');


         // assuming that you want query result by posting a variable
         var datasend = "account="+ project_id;

         $.ajax({

         type:'POST',
         url:'data.php',
         data:datasend,
         crossDomain: true,
         cache:false,
         success:function(msg){

//display image loader or text to alert the use that content is being loaded

         $('#loader').hide();

         if(msg=='true'){
alert('true');

// and display result

         $('#result').fadeIn('slow').prepend(msg);

}else{

alert('false');
}


         }

         });

         //})

         });


    </script>


<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
</body></html>
```

**data.php**

```
public function ajax_load()

{

        $project_id =$this->input->post('account');

         $this->db->select('Project_id');

        $this->db->from('proposal');

        $this->db->where('Project_id',$project_id);

        $query = $this->db->get()->row();

        if($query){
            echo "true";
        }else{
           echo "false";
        }

    }
```